# Install indicator-cpufreq as a package through web

Tags: package-management, downloads, setup

I have Ubuntu 11.10 version and I have problem that I can't download packages from software center neither through command line due to proxy settings problem

Does anybody know if I can get this package through web dowloads?

Comment: Check this out http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/indicator-cpufreq

Answer (score 1):

The following will download and install the Oneiric version of `indicator-cpufreq`, and a dependency it has, namely the `libcpufreq0` package.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cpufrequtils/libcpufreq0_007-1_i386.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~artfwo/+archive/ppa/+files/indicator-cpufreq_0.1.4-0ubuntu1~oneiric1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libcpufreq0_007-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i indicator-cpufreq_0.1.4-0ubuntu1~oneiric1_all.deb
```

---

If you are unable to access the internet at all from your workstation, you may simply download the two files on an another computer that *does* have internet access, and transfer the two `deb`files over using a USB key or some other medium.

- [libcpufreq0](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cpufrequtils/libcpufreq0_007-1_i386.deb) - Install first
- [indicator-cpufreq](https://launchpad.net/~artfwo/+archive/ppa/+files/indicator-cpufreq_0.1.4-0ubuntu1~oneiric1_all.deb) - Install second

You can install `deb` files by double-clicking on them in Ubuntu.